# nslookup not returning all ip addresses for host

Tags: dns, ip, ip-address, host, nslookup

I'm working on a program that tracks when search engines cannot find important files on my server.

From my computer I typed:

```
nslookup google.com
```

and I received 11 IP addresses in return all beginning with 74.125.226

I then tried:

```
dig google.com
```

and I still receive the same IP addresses.

When I navigate to here through searching: http://www.iplists.com/google.txt, the number of IP addresses is greater than 10 and that list includes ones starting with 64.249 which also appears in my server log.

Am I using the wrong linux tools to find every IP address associated with google? If so, what tools should I use?

I want to generate the IP address database myself rather than rely on someone's post of IP addresses just in case IP addresses are updated in the future.

Answer (score 0):

The keyword here is [GeoDNS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geodns): When website/service has many servers around the world (with the main purpose of providing the lowest possible latency to user requests), using GeoDNS it can respond with different IP addresses to DNS queries for the same hostname, based on the locaton of the DNS client that is making the query (of course it will try to respond with the IP address of the closest server).

Basically, there is no way you can retrieve all possible addresses just by querying DNS from one location. Also, google can add/remove/change addresses/servers on daily basis so you probably can never have the definite list (unless google publishes it somewhere).

The real-time example, this might help you:

https://www.whatsmydns.net/#A/www.google.com

Additional reading:

[What is the difference between Anycast and GeoDNS / GeoIP wrt HA?](https://serverfault.com/questions/325076/what-is-the-difference-between-anycast-and-geodns-geoip-wrt-ha)